Chaining GoCD pipelines not working with manual triggers
I have two pipelines built, and I want one to trigger when the other finishes running. Specifically, I want a database change script to run in the first pipeline, which then triggers the second script to fetch code to use it. It seems like this should be accomplished by setting the first pipeline as a material for the second pipeline, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here are the variables I've tried working with:

Automatic pipeline scheduling on the pipeline GENERAL tab
Trigger on completion of previous stage on the STAGE SETTINGS tab for the first stage in the pipeline
Fetch updates to this repository only on webhook or manual trigger in Advanced Settings for the material accessing the Git repository

I have found the first two to be linked. Setting one sets the other in the same way, though I would think that a pipeline could have more than one stage, and thus have different settings for them, but I have no need to set up multiple stages to look at this.
If Variable 1 is set to False, then triggering the upstream pipeline does NOT trigger the downstream pipeline. But if Variable 3 is set to fetch only on manual trigger, then running the pipeline does NOT fetch the current Git repo, but uses the last one it had fetched. And yet if I manually trigger a material update with the Trigger Update button on the Materials page, then somehow the pipeline notices this and runs the whole pipeline!
Problem statement: When running a production push, I want to trigger an upstream pipeline to fetch and run current database updates, which then triggers a downstream pipeline to fetch and install current code.
I can find no combination that works to do this. Any suggestions as to what else I should try?

I'm using this as a workaround, not as an actual solution:

I'm using a dummy Git repository for a material.
I set up a single pipeline, with two Stages.
The first stage runs a task command of git pull pointing to the location of my database update script.
The second stage runs a task command of git pull pointing to the location of my website to update.

I have additional commands, and additional syntax for the git pull, but this doesn't seem relevant to the central issue of manually triggering pipelines; I just got it to do what I want it to do.

Though doing this accomplishes what I want, I'm not marking this as an answer, since it doesn't really solve what was wrong with GoCD. If anyone ends up with a proper answer, then I could still mark that as accepted.
